# how can I color strings in a xlsx file

Tags: perl

I have a xls file which I want to color some strings differently

My xlsx file is like below lets call it **sample.xlsx**

```
>sp|Q96B97|SH3K1_HUMAN SH3 domain-containing kinase-binding protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SH3KBP1 PE=1 SV=2
MVEAIVEFDYQAQHDDELTISVGEIITNIRKEDGGWW
>sp|Q9UBS4|DJB11_HUMAN DnaJ homolog subfamily B member 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DNAJB11 PE=1 SV=1
KLALQLHPDRNPDDPQAQEKFQDLGAAYEVLSDSEKRKQYD
>sp|P61916|NPC2_HUMAN NPC intracellular cholesterol transporter 2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=NPC2 PE=1 SV=1
CQLSKGQSYSVNVTFTSNIQSKSSKAVVHGILMGVP
```

I want to read it and then save it when I color some letters. I want to color **D** in a yellow color

```
>sp|Q96B97|SH3K1_HUMAN SH3 domain-containing kinase-binding protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SH3KBP1 PE=1 SV=2
MVEAIVEF**D**YQAQH**DD**ELTISVGEIITNIRKE**D**GGWW
>sp|Q9UBS4|DJB11_HUMAN DnaJ homolog subfamily B member 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DNAJB11 PE=1 SV=1
KLALQLHPDRNP**DD**PQAQEKFQ**D**LGAAYEVLS**D**SEKRKQY**D**
>sp|P61916|NPC2_HUMAN NPC intracellular cholesterol transporter 2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=NPC2 PE=1 SV=1
CQLSKGQSYSVNVTFTSNIQSKSSKAVVHGILMGVP
```

I have tried to make it with no success

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel; 
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# Create an Excel workbook and worksheet
my $workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('output.xls'); 
my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'sample.xlsx' );
if ( !defined $workbook ) {
    die $parser->error(), ".\n";
}
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my $highlight = $workbook->add_format();
$highlight->set_bg_color('yellow');
my $row = 0;
while (<sample>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /$search_pattern/D;
  my $col = 0;
  my @fields = split;
  foreach my $field (@fields) {
    if ( $field =~ /$search_pattern/D ) {
      $worksheet->write_string($row, $col, $field, $highlight);
    }
    else {
      $worksheet->write_string($row, $col, $field);
    }
    $col++;
  }
  $row++;
}
$workbook->close()
```

every other line starts with `>sp` which should be ignored. The search pattern should apply to other line that does not have `>sp|`

**Edited**

Now I can read the xls and print them

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Reader::XLSX;

    my $reader   = Excel::Reader::XLSX->new();
    my $workbook = $reader->read_file( 'sample.xlsx' );
    if ( !defined $workbook ) {
        die $reader->error(), "\n";
    }
    for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) {
        my $sheetname = $worksheet->name();
        print "Sheet = $sheetname\n";
        while ( my $row = $worksheet->next_row() ) {
            while ( my $cell = $row->next_cell() ) {
                my $row   = $cell->row();
                my $col   = $cell->col();
                my $value = $cell->value();
                print "  Cell ($row, $col) = $value\n";
            }
        }
    }

#Sheet = Sheet1
#  Cell (0, 0) = >sp|Q96B97|SH3K1_HUMAN SH3 domain-containing kinase-binding protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=SH3KBP1 PE=1 SV=2
#  Cell (1, 0) = MVEAIVEFDYQAQHDDELTISVGEIITNIRKEDGGWW
#  Cell (2, 0) = >sp|Q9UBS4|DJB11_HUMAN DnaJ homolog subfamily B member 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=DNAJB11 PE=1 SV=1
#  Cell (3, 0) = KLALQLHPDRNPDDPQAQEKFQDLGAAYEVLSDSEKRKQYD
#  Cell (4, 0) = >sp|P61916|NPC2_HUMAN NPC intracellular cholesterol transporter 2 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=NPC2 PE=1 SV=1
#  Cell (5, 0) = CQLSKGQSYSVNVTFTSNIQSKSSKAVVHGILMGVP
```

Now here I want to focus on the **Cell(1,0)** and **Cell (3, 0)** and **Cell (5, 0)**

Comment: Doesn't look like a [mcve]. E.g. where are `sample` and `$search_pattern` defined? Furthermore: `my $workbook` is defined twice, i.e. the code won't compile due to `"my" variable $workbook masks earlier declaration in same scope...` error. The code won't compile due to `Unknown regexp modifier "/D"...` error.

Comment: Your input is unclear. Is it (a) every line starts with `>sp|` (i.e. incorrect line split in your question) or (b) every 2nd line starts with `>sp|` and the search pattern should apply to the other lines (i.e. the ones that don't start with `>sp|`)?

Comment: @Stefan Becker every other line starts with `>sp` which should be ignored. Yes the search pattern should apply to other line that does not have `>sp| `

Comment: @Stefan Becker sample is in the question now. If I could do it why would I ask for a help? I posted all I could do, but glad to explain whatever question you may have

Comment: Ok, so now you are showing us a program that reads from an Excel file rather than a text file, and prints to the screen. How are those related? Let's go step by step. What kind of input do you actually have? Text files or XLSX files?

Comment: @simbabque I have xls file, but I can always convert it to text if it is very different. I am extremely sorry for confusion. I mentioned it as xlsx in the very beginning of my question.

Comment: Programming is all about being exact. Let's take a step back and see what you actually want to do. Can you describe that in words please? No technical terms. Just what you have now, and what you want to have in the end.

Comment: @simbabque I have a xls files with many rows and a column. I don't want to change anything in the row that starts with  `>sp` but the other rows. so lets look at `Cell (1, 0) = MVEAIVEFDYQAQHDDELTISVGEIITNIRKEDGGWW` I want to color the D anywhere in this cell , so it will be MVEAIVEF`D`YQAQH`DD`ELTISVGEIITNIRKE`D`GGWW

Comment: OK, great. You've got code that parses your input XLS file. Now add Excel::Writer::XLSX to the mix, create a new workbook and worksheet there. Make sure you use different variable names, because `$workbook` and `$worksheet` are already taken. Also create the format in the new output workbook. Inside of the `while` loop, where you iterate over the input rows, now write them to the new output worksheet. Look at the content to decide whether you want to pass them through with `->write_string`, or if you need `->write_rich_string`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188837/discussion-between-simbabque-and-nik).

Answer (score 1):

For Excel::Writer::XLSX you need to use the [`write_rich_string` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX#write_rich_string(-$row,-$column,-$format,-$string,-...,-$cell_format-)) if you want to change individual parts of a single cell rather than a whole cell.

The syntax is a bit weird.

```
my $highlight = $workbook->add_format;
$highlight->set_bg_color('yellow');

$worksheet->write_rich_string( 'A1', 'ABC', $highlight, 'D', 'EFG' );
```

Break your string into segments, and precede each segment you want highlighted with the `$highlight` format object. Segments that have no object in front of them are not formatted.

This way of writing it makes it more clear. Remember Perl has list flattening, so empty lists `()` and extra commas just disappear, and the `=>` is a *fat comma*, the same as a `,`.

```
$worksheet->write_rich_string(
    'A1',                  # cell
     ()         => 'ABC',  # unformatted segment
     $highlight => 'D',    # highlighted
     ()         => 'EFG',  # unformatted
);
```

I am on Linux and don't have access to a real Excel. It seems Libre Office does not support this, or I am doing it wrong, so this is untested.

Comment: can you tell me which part of my code I should discard?

Comment: @nik if you edit your question and change the code in there so it at least compiles, I can try.

Comment: I am editing my effort, please comment anytime you get a chance